# Getting same records infinite number of times in kafka-connect-http source connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using Kafka Connect in distributed mode.I am using kafka-connect-http connector.
When I perform request to the specific REST API (get request). I get this back:
{"PWID": "1","LOT_NUMBER": "jz3177"}

But when I perform the request through this source connector, I get same records infinite number of times..

```
{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":false,"doc":"HTTP Record Value","field":"value"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"doc":"HTTP Record Key","
field":"key"},{"type":"int64","optional":true,"doc":"HTTP Record Timestamp","field":"timestamp"}],"optional":false,"name":"com.github.castorm.kafka.connect.http.Value","doc
":"Message Value"},"payload":{"value":"{\"PWID\":\"1\",\"LOT_NUMBER\":\"jz3177\"}","key":"1","timestamp":1623412068790}}
{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":false,"doc":"HTTP Record Value","field":"value"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"doc":"HTTP Record Key","
field":"key"},{"type":"int64","optional":true,"doc":"HTTP Record Timestamp","field":"timestamp"}],"optional":false,"name":"com.github.castorm.kafka.connect.http.Value","doc
":"Message Value"},"payload":{"value":"{\"PWID\":\"1\",\"LOT_NUMBER\":\"jz3177\"}","key":"1","timestamp":1623412099052}}
{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"string","optional":false,"doc":"HTTP Record Value","field":"value"},{"type":"string","optional":true,"doc":"HTTP Record Key","
field":"key"},{"type":"int64","optional":true,"doc":"HTTP Record Timestamp","field":"timestamp"}],"optional":false,"name":"com.github.castorm.kafka.connect.http.Value","doc
":"Message Value"},"payload":{"value":"{\"PWID\":\"1\",\"LOT_NUMBER\":\"jz3177\"}","key":"1","timestamp":1623412129386}}

.
.
.
same thing infinite number of times
```

I expect it only once as I get only one record as response from my rest api

connector configuration:

```
{
    "connector.class": "com.github.castorm.kafka.connect.http.HttpSourceConnector",
    "http.request.url": " my request url",
    "http.timer.interval.millis": "30000",
    "kafka.topic": "http-topic3",
    "http.request.template.factory": "com.github.castorm.kafka.connect.http.request.template.NoTemplateFactory",
    "http.request.headers": "Accept:application/json",
    "tasks.max": 1,
    "max.retries": "0",
    "http.response.record.offset.pointer": "key=/PWID"
}
```

what am I missing in properties?

Comment: Have you tried to change this `"http.timer.interval.millis": "30000"` setting?

Comment: Kafka Connect is primarily meant to poll records continuously, **not** "one and done". If you want only one event, then use a standard HTTP client and pass that data to Kafka

Comment: @OneCricketeer if I apply transforms and get only this {"PWID":"1","LOT_NUMBER":"jz3177"} then, is there any way to avoid duplicate records getting injected into topic ??  (PWID is my primary key)

Comment: I don't expect "one and done"...I expect the same record not to be inserted again and again..No duplicated data in topic..

Comment: We dont know what data your HTTP server returns, but if your URL or the API data isn't changing, then why do you expect it to be different? The Connector knows nothing about the previous records, and cannot deduplicate data. Your consumers should be responsible for handling more-than-once consumption, i.e. duplicates

Comment: @AchyutVyas I tried setting "http.timer.interval.millis": "1800000" ..but my first http request is also made after 1800000 ms..

Comment: Yes thatshow http.timer.interval.millis works. It will wait for specified time. 
even not sure how to start the connector immediately and wait for timer..